# How to fix an andriod tablet which is frozen on the startup menu

Tags: tablet

The tablet won't go past the allwinner startup menu. A restart was tried but it never worked. This is a Chinese android tablet. It is an *allwinner A20*. Operating system android 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the default recovery on your Android tablet and do a factory reset. To do so turn off the tablet and then while holding the Power button press Volume Down and hold for about 10 seconds. If this doesn't work try Volime Up or both. You should be now in the recovery and you can navigate with Volume Up/Down and confirm with Power button. If this doesn't work then your device may need a bit more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mid android phablet.  Had some issues too, but not that one.  Here is a link, they have a lot of suggestions for android tablets (under forums heading, then android tablet): http://www.androidtablets.net/search/33094/?q=android+tablet+frozen&o=relevance

I did a query with "android frozen tablet" in the search.  The search engine is somewhat off on the queries, so search using some of the words or fewer words, otherwise it might not bring up any hits, when there are suggestions/solutions.  This query brought up some suggestions with the mid tablet.  The second suggestion seems possible as many of my issues with the tablet were resolved with simple things, but not things you'd think would be the solution.....It said if frozen to let the battery run down all the way, and then plug it into the power adapter and the other person says there's started working then?!  Good Luck!